# Clojure: commute before alter within one transaction causes the transaction to fail

Tags: clojure, transactions, stm

I'm new to Clojure and have been trying to understand its transaction model.
When playing with `alter` and `commute`, I noticed that if I `alter` a ref after `commute` it, then the transaction will not commit anything (or makes no change to anything).

For example:

```
(def counter (ref 0))
(def i (ref 0))
(future (dosync
          (ref-set counter 1)
          (ref-set i 1)
          (commute counter inc)
          (alter counter inc)))
```

Both `@counter` and `@i` will be 0, but if I swap `commute` and `alter` or use two `commute`s or two `alter`s in this case it will produce the desired result (3 and 1, respectively).

I've read some posts explaining that the behavior of `commute` and `alter` is a bit different in that `commute` is actually executed twice in a transaction (one where it stands, the other at the "commit" stage) and ignores inconsistent snapshots of the ref. I'm just confused by the strange behavior of the combination of these two.

Could anyone help explain how it works? Thanks in advance!

Comment: clojure 1.8: it outputs in repl `{:status :failed, :val #error { :cause "Can't set after commute" :via [{:type java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException ...` so don't `alter` after `commute`. Couldn't find any specific doc for it - just the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LockingTransaction.java#L428)

Answer (score 0):

The `commute` function is useful only in very narrow (i.e. rare) circumstances, where it ***may*** reduce lock contention at the cost of additional re-tries of the update function.  It also makes the mental model of the transaction much more complicated, as your example shows (I had never seen this particular problem before, for example).

IMHO it is almost always better to use `alter` instead of `commute` since `alter` is simpler and more bulletproof.  Indeed, I would usually consider the use of `commute` to be a case of *premature optimization*.